# Adding Binary to Existing JDK Docker Image

Tags: gitlab-ci

My [.gitlab-ci.yaml](https://gitlab.com/kevinmeredith/ci-cd-test/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml)'s [job](https://gitlab.com/kevinmeredith/ci-cd-test/-/jobs/1674012290) failed due to `docker` not being available on the `PATH`:

```
[error] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/builds     
 /kevinmeredith/ci-cd-test/target/docker"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

How can I find an existing JDK image, preferably `openjdk`, that also includes `docker`? If it's not easy to find, how can I add `docker` to the `openjdk:8` image?

Answer (score 2):

By running the `openjdk:8` Image [from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=description) in a local container, I found that it is based upon Debian Linux 11 ("Bullseye"):

```
❯ docker run --rm -it openjdk:8
Unable to find image 'openjdk:8' locally
8: Pulling from library/openjdk
...
Digest: sha256:9d233cf187b7022a8f285ed7c162b0a87624de1dbe09dcc499bfab83c22a66d5
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:8
root@a131b4c32c2a:/#
root@a131b4c32c2a:/# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l
```

[Here are Docker's instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) for installing Docker within Debian. When running within CI as `root` you will want to skip `sudo` as it's not installed in the image. So here are some modified commands that worked interactively:

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
apt-get update #again
apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

These could go into the `before_script:` part of [your .gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/kevinmeredith/ci-cd-test/-/blob/e4724c69ce3d51d97b474c48ef732a1007a710cc/.gitlab-ci.yml), but they will be executed *every time the CI runs* (adding to the CI minutes that the pipeline uses).

Better would be to build an image of your own based `FROM openjdk:8` with a Dockerfile, where these steps are then `RUN`. Then publish this image to your GitLab project's [container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#build-and-push-by-using-gitlab-cicd), and specify it in your CI in place of the `openjdk:8`. But that's more involved, see if you can get your build to run first.

Comment: Hi @mike - thanks. Adding those 4 lines did [not work](https://gitlab.com/kevinmeredith/ci-cd-test/-/jobs/1731774552): `bin/bash: line 137: dnf: command not found`. I don't see `dnf` under `ls /bin/dnf` for `openjdk:8` image.

Comment: My apologies, I have just now _actually run a local docker container_ with `openjdk:8`, and it appears that it is actually based on Debian, despite what the Docker Hub page says.  So that would mean you need to install Docker using Debian instructions, and `apt-get`.  I'll find some and update my answer.